# How to allow ads in some websites with Epiphany?

Tags: release-juno, epiphany, web-browser

I want to enable ads in certain websites, but not globally, create an exception list of some sort for the ad blocker. Is that possible? Without checking and unchecking "block ads" in preferences, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been requested several times, but unfortunately it's not currently possible. https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/epiphany/issues/268 has been reported to add this functionality.

May 2019 edit: this will be possible in Epiphany 3.34 using the security popover that appears when you click the address bar lock icon; various website permissions will be available to change there.

Answer (score 2):

As of Epiphany 3.32 (maybe some earlier post-3.24 versions), you can [edit the list of filter files using `dconf-editor` or `gsettings`](https://askubuntu.com/a/470041/55386)

So, you should (haven't tested) be able to define a filter file with exceptions according to the [AdBlock Plus syntax](https://adblockplus.org/en/filters), upload it somewhere, and put the link in the `adblock-filters` setting.

You might even be able to get away with dropping a filter file in `~/.cache/epiphany/adblock/` (where filters defined in `adblock-filters` are downloaded), not sure.

Answer (score 0):

### Since Epiphany 3.24 `filters.list` file was removed (Thanks to [Michael C.](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/users/10316/michael-c)). More [Info](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/epiphany/commit/3a5bfb106fc136ef087f91c08e573350932a1cf3)

---

### From [askubuntu@470040](https://askubuntu.com/questions/470040/how-to-customize-or-debug-ad-blocking-on-gnome-web-epiphany-browser)

In the file

```
$HOME/.config/epiphany/adblock/filters.list
```

, you can set filter lists... one on each line and with `;` at the end of each line

Comment: So what shoud I write in `filters.list` to allow ads on example.com?

Comment: @cristianmos Have a look at this guide from [Adblock Plus](https://adblockplus.org/en/filters) under `Defining exception rules`. The syntax is the same.

Comment: As a disclaimer: I don't use Epiphany. About your question, I have two solutions in mind: First is to use a service like github to upload your filterlist and place it into that file (the url of the raw code/text). And second is to go to the Epiphany website https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/epiphany/issues and ask directly to that thirdparty app how to do what you want to achieve within their system

Comment: The `filters.list` file was removed in Epiphany 3.24 so you might as well just delete it. (Epiphany really ought to delete it automatically.) See https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/epiphany/commit/3a5bfb106fc136ef087f91c08e573350932a1cf3.